# Get the results as 120 using five zeros

Tags: algorithm

One of my friend was asked this question in the interview.

You have 5 zeros. using these 5 zeros and any mathematical functions, you have to get the result of 120.

He could not answer this. Neither I am able to see any valid answers.

Does anyone have any solution to this?

Comment: Define "mathematical function". Is the function that maps (0,0,0,0,0) to 120 allowed?

Comment: Yes -- factorial maps 5 to 120, so you need a function that maps 0 to 1, add the results and take the factorial. The only real variation is how you map from 0 to 1 -- and there are *lots* of possibilities along that line.

Comment: @Jerry - Yes. There are lot of possibilities. Most striking would be the factorial I think and thats what was expected as answer in that interview. :)

Comment: Is it just me or is the expression "you have 5 zeroes" meaningless? Better: "compute 120 with an expression that mentions the number 0 exactly 5 times and that does not mention any other numeric constant".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming-related.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
( 0! + 0! + 0! + 0! + 0! ) ! = 120
```

Answer (score 17):

(cos(0) + cos(0) + cos(0) + cos(0) + cos(0))!

Answer (score 13):

I can do it with 4 zeros: ((0! + 0! + 0!)! - 0!)!

Answer (score 5):

Use [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)

```
0! = 1
(0! + 0! + 0! + 0! + 0!)! = 120
```

Answer (score 4):

I recently came across this beautiful approach to represent any number using one zero!

---

The explanation is as follows:

Consider a right-angled triangle with sides (1,1,√2). Thus, 

√2 = Sec ( Tan-1( 0! ) ). 
Now, consider a another right-angled triangle with sides (1,√2, √3). Here, 
√3 = Sec ( Tan-1 (Sec ( Tan-1( 0! ) ) ) ). 
Extrapolating this idea futher, for any number x, we can represent √x using one 0 as, 
√x = Sec ( Tan-1 (…… Sec ( Tan-1 (0!)) ……)), where Sec ( Tan-1 ….) is taken x-1 times.

---

There you go, 120 can be represented as, 
√14400 = Sec ( Tan-1 (…… Sec ( Tan-1 (0!)) ……)), with Sec ( Tan-1 ….) taken 14399 times.

Answer (score 2):

I would buy the *pure* solution by @Iarsman, but I bet they were looking for something like:

factorial(not(0)+not(0)+not(0)+not(0)+not(0))

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show you *really* know mathematical functions better than the interviewer, state it in terms of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms:

SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS0 = 120

Or if you want to be too clever by half:

0/0 = 120 [Yes, that's not good practice, but it's as justifiable as any other answer]

Or if you want to show that mathematicians are often also comfortable using programming operators in the right circumstance:

(!0+!0+!0+!0+!0)!

I admit when I first saw it I was confused, because mostly this sort of question assumes that by mathematical function you mean "plus times minus divide" and maybe exponentiation. And I agree factorials are the intended answer. I agree it's an amusing question, and maybe it's sour grapes, but I really don't see the point of distinguishing people who've seen too many of these "think of the trick" questions from those who haven't, which is what this question does. (OK, it also sorts out who's never heard of a factorial, but so would asking "what's a factorial". This just makes sure you get the middle ground.)

Comment: I think this question was asked in interview only to see how you approach problem rather than expect correct answer.

Comment: Sachin: It seems probable (whether or not the interviewer had a preconcived idea of what that would be). Indeed, whether the question was good or not, an interesting question for stackxxxxx would be "What answer to this should you look for from someone to hire".

I'd _like_ someone who gave the successor function answer, but I'd prefer to _hire_ someone who got the obvious stuff out of the way first and didn't seem to be trying to one-up me. OTOH, I hope it'd be clear from my attitude whether I'm asking "guess the right answer" or "impress me with weird ingenuity" :)

Comment: I like this approach, the least one can say is: It doesn't succ :)

Answer (score 2):

"Mathematical" functions, hmmm, what else? Chemical ones?

```
let
   zeroes = [0,0,0,0,0]
   five = length zeroes
in five*five*five - five
```

Turns out we do not even need the zeores:

```
let
   zeroes = [[], [], [], [], []]
   five = length zeroes
in five*five*five - five
```

Comment: `What else?` ... Programming ones? ;) e.g. `int return120() { return 120; }`

Comment: @JamesWebster What you have written is indeed not a mathematical function, as it has no input. But I assume that it is not allowed to just write `120` - if it were allowed, we wouldn't even need this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use Factorial .
```

fact(fact(0)+....+fact(0))

Answer (score 0):

0^0*1111 = 1111 (2 zeroes)

1111000 = 120 in binary (remaining 3 zeroes used here)

Answer (score 0):

(0!0!*0!0!)-0! =(11*11) -1 =121-1 =120 is how i solved in an interview and the interviewer was amazed :)

Answer (score 0):

how about one zero :P

**(((((0!)++)++)++)++)!**

Answer (score 0):

RoL(RoL(RoL(RoL(NOT(RoL(NOT(RoL(NOT(RoL(NOT(0)))))))))))
One zero strictly logical using Windows Programming Calc